# Unlock Variable in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I have already ask this question and I thought I found a solution but I am stuck yet again. I am having issues with unlock variables.

I'm running a SQL Server Agent Job which has a script task with Microsoft Visual C# 2008 which is below.  I haven't listed the variables in Script task editor read/write variable list. In my SSIS package I have For Loop Container which loop over this script task until the file does exist.

https://mitchellsql.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/ssis-script-taskdoes-file-exists/

```
  public void Main()
    {

        // Lock variables
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::FolderPath");
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::FileExistsFlg");

        // Create a variables 'container' to store variables
        Variables vars = null;

        // Add variables from the VariableDispenser to the variables 'container'
        Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);

        string filepath;
        filepath = vars["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
        vars["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = File.Exists(filepath);

        // Release the locks
        vars.Unlock();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;      
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**

I get this error when the SQL Job fails but the package runs perfectly when run via Visual Studio:

Message

> Executed as user: PSFACAMDWHSQL1\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.4270.0 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   12:26:43  Error: 2015-03-03 12:41:25.79     Code: 0xC001404F
>   Source: For Loop Container      Description: This Variables collection
>   has already been unlocked. The Unlock method is called only once on a
>   dispensed Variables collection.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:26:43  Finished:
>   12:41:25  Elapsed:  881.921 seconds.  The package execution failed. 
>   The step failed.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Be certain you are not getting confused with variable scope. You can have two identically named variables in a different scope and it makes things confusing

Comment: @Nick Apologies not sure I fully understand.

Comment: In this example, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variabledispenser.getvariables.aspx the two variables are first `LockForRead` _before_ `GetVariables` is called. This is different to your code. Try using `LockForWrite` before you call `GetVariables`

Comment: @Nick Only one variable is LockforRead and the second is LockForWrite both are not LockforRead. Not sure if I misunderstood.

Comment: Lockforwhatever... your code is different to the sample code in the link I posted. The link makes two other calls before `GetVariables` that you don't... look at the code in the link I posted and compare it to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You probably listed the variable in the Script task editor read/write variable list  ("User::FileExistsFlg") and then in your code you lock it again. Its one or the other. When I created an example listing a user variable twice my SSIS package hung - I probably did not wait long enough for it to err out.
This worked fine as long as I did not list the variable User::A1:

Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::a1");

```
        // Create a variables 'container' to store variables
        Variables vars = null;

        // Add variables from the VariableDispenser to the variables 'container'
        Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);

        //string filepath;
       // filepath = vars["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
       // vars["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = File.Exists(filepath);
        vars["User::a1"].Value = 35;
        MessageBox.Show(vars["User::a1"].Value.ToString());
        // Release the locks
        vars.Unlock();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: I didn't list the variable in the script task editor.